# Tornado Server using most of the cpu while using tornado-sockjs and only two clients.

Tags: python, tornado, sockjs, sockjs-tornado

I am using Tornado Server, 4.4.2 and pypy  5.9.0 and python 2.7.13, 
hosted on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

A new client logs in and a new class is created and passed the socket, so dialog can be maintained.  I am using **a global** clients[] list to contain the classes. initial dialog looks like :

```
clients = []

class RegisterWebSocket(SockJSConnection):
  # intialize the class and handle on-open (some things left out) 

    def on_open(self,info):
        self.ipaddress = info.headers['X-Real-Ip']

    def on_message(self, data):
        coinlist = []
        msg = json.loads(data)
        if 'coinlist' in msg:
            coinlist = msg['coinlist']
        if 'currency' in msg:
            currency = msg['currency']
            tz = pendulum.timezone('America/New_York')
            started = pendulum.now(tz).to_day_datetime_string()
            ws = WebClientUpdater(self, self.clientid, coinlist,currency, 
                 started, self.ipaddress)
            clients.append(ws)
```

The ws class is shown below and I use a tornado periodiccallback to update the clients with their specific info every 20 seconds

```
class WebClientUpdater(SockJSConnection):

    def __init__(self, ws,id, clist, currency, started, ipaddress):
        super(WebClientUpdater,self).__init__(ws.session)
        self.ws = ws
        self.id = id
        self.coinlist = clist
        self.currency = currency
        self.started = started
        self.ipaddress = ipaddress
        self.location = loc
        self.loop = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(self.updateCoinList, 
                  20000, io_loop=tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance())                                    
        self.loop.start()
        self.send_msg('welcome '+ id)

    def updateCoinList(self):
        pdata = db.getPricesOfCoinsInCurrency(self.coinlist,self.currency)
        self.send(dict(priceforcoins = pdata))

    def send_msg(self,msg):
        self.send(msg)
```

I also start at 60 second periodiccallback at startup, to monitor the clients for closed connections and remove them from the client[] list. Which I put on the startup line to call a def internally like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(options.port) 
    ScheduleSocketCleaning()
```

and

```
def ScheduleSocketCleaning():
    def cleanSocketHouse():
        print "checking sockets"
        for x in clients:
            if x.is_closed:
              x = None

    clients[:] = [y for y in clients if not y.is_closed ]

    loop = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(cleanSocketHouse, 60000,                             
          io_loop=tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance())
    loop.start()
```

If I monitor the server using TOP I see that it uses 4% cpu typical with bursts to 60+ immediately, but later, say after a few hours it becomes in the 90% and stays there.

I have used strace and I see an enormous amount of Stat calls on the same files with errors shown in the strace -c view, but I cannot find any errors in a text file using -o trace.log. How can I find those errors ?

But I also notice that most of the time is consumed in epoll_wait.

%time

- 41.61    0.068097           7      9484           epoll_wait
- 26.65    0.043617           0    906154      2410 stat
- 15.77    0.025811           0    524072           read
- 10.90    0.017840         129       138           brk
- 2.41    0.003937           9       417           madvise
- 2.04    0.003340           0    524072           lseek
- 0.56    0.000923           3       298           sendto
- 0.06    0.000098           0     23779           gettimeofday
- 100.00    0.163663               1989527      2410 total

Notice 2410 errors above.

When I view the strace output stream using attached pid, I just see endless Stat calls on the same files..

Can someone advise me as to how to better debug this situation?  With only two clients and 20 seconds between client updates, I would expect the CPU usage (there are no other users of the site during this prototype stage) would be less than 1% or thereabouts.

Comment: I should also add, I have nginx server in front of tornado forwarding requests.  Also on the client side I have reconnect javascript doing reconnects if the connection closes.  I have monitored it for proper behavior and it appears to be working as desired.

Comment: You have a memory leak. You never close PeriodicCallbacks. Thus the number of timers raises and after some time you have so many that they take whole cpu time. This is seen on `epoll_wait` because that's where the scheduling actually happens.

Comment: @freakish Thank you .. How should I close PeriodicCallbacks ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close PeriodicCallbacks, otherwise its a memory leak. You do that by simply calling `.close()` on a PeriodicCallback object. One way to deal with that is in your periodic cleaning task:

```
def cleanSocketHouse():
    global clients
    new_clients = []
    for client in clients:
        if client.is_closed:
            # I don't know why you call it loop,
            # .timer would be more appropriate
            client.loop.close()
        else:
            new_clients.append(client)
    clients = new_clients
```

I'm not sure how accurate `.is_closed` is (some testing is required). The other way is to alter `updateCoinList`. The `.send()` method should fail when the client is no longer connected, right? Therefore `try: except:` should do the trick:

```
def updateCoinList(self):
    global clients
    pdata = db.getPricesOfCoinsInCurrency(self.coinlist,self.currency)
    try:
        self.send(dict(priceforcoins = pdata))
    except Exception:
        # log exception?
        self.loop.close()
        clients.remove(self)  # you should probably use set instead of list
```

If `,send()` actually doesn't fail (for whatever reason, I'm not that familiar with Tornado) then stick to the first solution.